# Why doesn't accept() block?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm new in socket programming under Linux (UNIX) sockets.
I found the following code in the Internet, for a tcp-server that spawns a thread for each connection.
However it doesn't work.
the accept() function returns instantly, and doesn't wait for connection.
What am I doing wrong ?

this is the code

```
int main(int argv, char *args[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sd, port;

    port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /*--- create socket ---*/
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( sd < 0 )
        panic("socket");

    /*--- bind port/address to socket ---*/
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = port;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;                   /* any interface */
    if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
        panic("bind");

    /*--- make into listener with 10 slots ---*/
    if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
        panic("listen")

    /*--- begin waiting for connections ---*/
    else
    {   int sd;
        pthread_t child;
        FILE *fp;

        while (1)                         /* process all incoming clients */
        {
            sd = accept(sd, 0, 0);     /* accept connection */
            fp = fdopen(sd, "wr+");           /* convert into FILE* */
            pthread_create(&child, 0, servlet, fp);       /* start thread */
            pthread_detach(child);                      /* don't track it */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `accept` and then if it's `-1` you're not checking `errno`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005067/c-failing-at-socket-accept-method

Comment: Ok, lesson learned, don't trust code you downloaded from a web-site. even examples fail often !

Comment: Fine, but just don't forget to choose the correct answer.

Comment: Besides the shadowing of `sd`, the call to `accept()` overwrites the listening socket descriptor. As this will work for **one** call to `accept()`, it surely won't work in a loop (as shown in the OP's code snippet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are shadowing the `sd` variable, passing an invalid socket to `accept()` which causes it to fail immediately.

It will likely return `EBADF` to signal a bad file descriptor. You would have noticed if you checked the return value in your code.

You should enable more compiler warnings, to catch things like these. With GCC you can use the `-Wshadow` option to enable such a warning.

Comment: It's not aliasing, it's shadowing. Aliasing would mean to have a variable that points to the same location as the other, and thus wouldn't be errorneous. :) Also, compiler warnings probably won't help, as this is perfect valid and shouldn't produce a warning with `-Wall` in GCC.

Comment: Ah you're right, it's neither part of `-Wall`, nor of `-Wextra` though. It has to be specified manually.

Answer (score 2):

You're not checking the return value of `accept()` call. Most likely it's returning an error.

Comment: Check unwind's answer. Anyway, you must include that check in your code.

Answer (score 2):

there's a redefinition of sd variable

```
int sd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems:

1) You are missing a comma on panic("listen")

2) You are declaring "sd" twice (one at main() one at else)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 30000

int main(int argv, char *args[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sd, port;

    port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /*--- create socket ---*/
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /*--- bind port/address to socket ---*/
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = port;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;                   /* any interface */

    bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    /*--- make into listener with 10 slots ---*/
    listen(sd, 10);

    /*--- begin waiting for connections ---*/
    pthread_t child;
    FILE *fp;

    while (1)                         /* process all incoming clients */
    {
        printf("before accept\n");
        sd = accept(sd, 0, 0);     /* accept connection */
        fp = fdopen(sd, "wr+");           /* convert into FILE* */
        //pthread_create(&child, 0, servlet, fp);       /* start thread */
        //pthread_detach(child);                      /* don't track it */
        printf("After accept\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

their is a redefinition of variable sd.

```
int sd; // at line 3 and 26
```